# C# DNX parsing HTML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-parsing, dnx

I am trying to parse HTML on DNX (.NET Execution Environment), but I can't find way to do it. As I know DNX was made primary for cross platform web development, therefore there should be something?

Comment: [Don't use Regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1822514)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore). It's port [HtmlAgilityPack library](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to .net core, which used to parsing html on full .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally manage to find a way to parse `HTML` documents. I have used
`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` class.

It is fully supported on DNX, here is [doucmentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I guess your HTML will have to we well-formed XML in that case. No room for any errors, like <br> instead of <br /> ?