# C# taghelper string replacement

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a .net core taghelper that will turn simple markup into the markup I need for my mobile and desktop menus and I need some help/refresher on what the best way to accomplish the string manipulation would be as I'm unfortunately rusty at the moment. The starting markup example is below.

```
<topnav>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
    <div>
        <span>Nested Section</span>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
    </div>
</topnav>
```

I would like to duplicate this structure while identifying...

```
<span>Nested Section</span>
```

and...

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
```

which would be inserted into two different templates to create...

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
<div class='accordion'>
    <div class='title'>
        <span>Nested Section</span>
        <i class='icon'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and...

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
<div class='dropdown'>
    <span>Nested Section</span>
    <i class='icon'></i>
    <div class='menu'>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

which would then be inserted into a third template to create...

```
<nav class='sidebar menu'>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
    <div class='accordion'>
        <div class='title'>
            <span>Nested Section</span>
            <i class='icon'></i>
        </div>
        <div class='content'>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<section class='top menu'>
    <nav class='computer'>
        <a href="#"><img alt="logo"/></a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
        <div class='dropdown'>
            <span>Nested Section</span>
            <i class='icon'></i>
            <div class='menu'>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class='mobile'>
        <a href="#"><img alt="logo"/></a>
        <a href='#'><i class='sidebar icon'></i></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

I already have the templates built and just need to complete the string parsing from the original topnav tag's content and insert it appropriately. I would also like the solution to work with menus that require more than one nesting such as...

```
<topnav>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test1">Test1</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test2">Test2</a>
    <div>
        <span>Nested Section</span>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test3">Test3</a>
        <div>
            <span>Nested Section 2</span>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test5">Test5</a>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test6">Test6</a>
        </div>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test4">Test4</a>
    </div>
</topnav>
```

I assume regex is the way to go, but I wanted to gather some opinions before going in the wrong direction. It is also possible to add to the original markup if needed, but I require it to be as minimal as possible. Please provide examples!

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into using an XML parser before considering RegEx.

Comment: I'd assume that staying away from XML is the best option since it is being more or less completely removed from .net core? I'm specifically asking for .net core taghelper best practices more or less.

Comment: Then maybe Html Agility Pack for .NET Core? https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093825/c-sharp-dnx-parsing-html while looking at references to the HTMLAgilityPack, was System.Xml.Linq.XDocument what you were directing me to in your first comment? It seems to be the easiest to use.